# Select python files based on matching content inside file

Tags: bash

I have recently created some code that will search for python files belonging to a directory, and it will invest into searching all sub-directories for these python files. All whilst excluding those files I specify.

I then want to filter this search further by selecting on those python files that contain keywords in them. For example, I want to return all python files which contains the keyword as content 'url'.

Here is what I have attempted:

```
find ML*/* -not -path "*/venv/**"  -not -path "*/ENV_DIR/**" -print0 | \
 while read -d $'\0' file; do if [[ "$file" != */venv && "$file" != */ENV_DIR ]]; \
 then echo ~/$file  | grep '.py$'; fi; done | while IFS= read -r lines; \
 do if [ $lines == 'url' ]; then echo $lines; fi ; done
```

However this prints nothing because the last `while` loop does not search into the content, it instead prints out the path to the file.

I have attempted the following to read the content (by using gawk):

```
find ML*/* -not -path "*/venv/**"  -not -path "*/ENV_DIR/**" -print0 | \
 while read -d $'\0' file; do if [[ "$file" != */venv && "$file" != */ENV_DIR ]]; \
 then echo ~/$file  | grep '.py$'; fi; done | while IFS= read -r lines; \
 do gawk '{ print }' $lines; done
```

However, this will only print out the first file content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with single command

```
find ./ -not -path "*/venv/**"  -not -path "*/ENV_DIR/**" -name "*.py" -exec  grep -H 'url' {} \;
```

- `-not -path` excludes paths
- `-name "*.py"` matches only files with extension
- `-exec` executes command for each file found
- `grep -H` looks for matching line and prints filename
- `{}` is replaced by the current file name being processed
- `\;` is used to specify last argument

Comment: This worked as expected! although, If I wished to not print out the file-content and return only the file containing the content, how is this done? Your script prints out the content and file.

Comment: replace `-H` with `-l`